# If $f \colon [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ satisfies $\vert f'' \vert \le k$ then $\vert f \vert \le \frac{k}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f \colon [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function s.t. $f(-1)=f(1)=0$ and there exists $k>0$ s.t. $\vert f''(x) \vert \le k$ for every $x \in [-1,1]$. 
>   Show that 
>   $$
> \max_{[-1,1]}\vert f \vert \le \frac{k}{2}.
> $$

The book suggests: take $x_0\in (-1,1)$ such that $\vert f(x_0)\vert$ is maximum and use Taylor.

Following this hint, I write:
$$
f(x_0+h)=f(x_0) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}h^2
$$
The linear term, $f'(x_0)=0$ (since the point is in the interior of $[-1,1]$ and is a maximum or a minimum for $f$).

Now how can I conclude? I can't see how to use the hypotesis $f(-1)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: You are missing an integral term in your Taylor expansion.

Comment: @vanna Am I? I used Taylor expansion with Lagrange remainder. Did I have to add an integral remainder? My book doesn't mention it...

Comment: Sorry about that I took $\xi$ for $x_0$, your expression is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x_0$ such that $|f(x_0)$ is maximized, and note that $f'(x_0)=0$. Using Taylor, we have
$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)h+R(h)\text{ where } |R(h)|\leq \left|\frac{\max_{x\in [-1,1]}|f''(x)|}{2}h^2\right|$$
and since $f'(x_0)=0$ this simplifies to $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+R(h)$. If we take $h$ such that $|h|\leq 1$ and $x_0+h=\pm 1$ (which is always possible), we get $0=f(x_0)+R(h)$ so
$$|f(x_0)|=|R(h)|\leq\left|\frac{\max_{x\in [-1,1]}|f''(x)|}{2}h^2\right|\leq \frac{k}{2}|h|^2\leq \frac{k}{2}$$ 
which completes the proof.

Comment: Feel so stupid... it was so easy! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. +1 to your question for doing almost all the work yourself, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Try choosing $h$ so that $x_0+h$ is either $-1$ or $1$ (whichever results in the smaller $h$).